# FlatMap and Map in Apache Beam

Tags: python, apache-beam, flatmap

Does FlatMap and Map function in Apache Beam for python is running on parallel?

```
(p
      | 'GetJava' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input)
      | 'GetImports' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda line: startsWith(line, keyword))
      | 'PackageUse' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda line: packageUse(line, keyword))
      | 'TotalUse' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
      | 'Top_5' >> beam.transforms.combiners.Top.Of(5, by_value)
      | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_prefix)
   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parallelization in your pipeline occurs after the `ReadFromText` transform. That transform separates directories into multiple files, and files into segments.

Each segment is processed serially in a single worker, so the output of your first `FlatMap` transform will go down into the other `FlatMap` serially - but you will have many instances of `FlatMap+FlatMap` running over each file segment.

Let me know if that answers your question : )